# Extract text from PDF files in a directory using PyPDF2

Tags: python, text, directory, extract, pypdf

I would like to extract text from pdf's in a directory to text files in another directory ( convert PDF=> .txt) with PyPDF2

I have read the information here : https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/

But I did not find information on batch converting the files

```
import PyPDF2
pdfFileObj = open('meetingminutes.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pdfReader.numPages

pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
pageObj.extractText()
```

I looking for a solution to convert pdf files from a directory and convert them to .txt files with same names in another directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the following code

```
import os
import PyPDF2

PDFS_FOLDER = '/absolute/path/of/your/pdf/folder'
TEXTS_FOLDER = '/absolute/path/of/your/txt/folder/which/is/already/created'

def get_all_pdfs(folder_path):
    """
    :param folder_path: absolute folder path of the pdfs
    :return: a list with all the absolute path of pdfs
    """
    return os.listdir(folder_path)

def create_absolute_path(root_path, file_name):
    """
    :param root_path: absolute route path
    :param file_name: file name
    :return: absolute path of the file name
    """
    root_path = root_path + '/' if root_path[-1] != '/' else root_path
    return "%s%s" %(root_path, file_name)

def convert_pdf_to_text(pdf_path):
    """
    :param pdf_path:
    :return: bytearray with all the pages content
    """
    pdfFileObj = open(pdf_path, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    number_of_pages = pdfReader.getNumPages()
    text_byte_array = bytearray()
    for page_number in range(number_of_pages):
        current_page = pdfReader.getPage(page_number)
        page_content = bytearray(current_page.extractText().encode('utf-8'))
        text_byte_array.extend(page_content)
    return text_byte_array

def convert_pdf_extension_to_text(pdf_file_name):
    """
    :param pdf_file_name: string which contains a pdf file name
    :return: string with the filename but with .txt extension instead of .pdf
    """
    return "%s.txt" %(pdf_file_name.split('.pdf', 1)[0])

def save_text_to_folder(text, target_path):
    """
    :param text: byte or bytearray
    :param target_path:
    :return:
    """
    with open(target_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(text)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_pdfs = get_all_pdfs(PDFS_FOLDER)
    for pdf_file_name in all_pdfs:
        abs_path_pdf = create_absolute_path(PDFS_FOLDER, pdf_file_name)
        text = convert_pdf_to_text(abs_path_pdf)
        text_path = convert_pdf_extension_to_text(pdf_file_name)
        target_text_path = create_absolute_path(TEXTS_FOLDER, text_path)
        save_text_to_folder(text, target_text_path)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you Dear Alex for your response, I get this error when executing it, I did not find a solution to that yet...

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\filters.py in decompress(data)
     47 
     48     def decompress(data):
---> 49         return zlib.decompress(data)
     50 
     51     def compress(data):

error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check

Comment: Hi, try to use normal python not anaconda. Before I've posted this, I've tested it on my local environment and it works